# How to animate two pics using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, animation

I have two images and i want to animate these on click of a button.i want when i click on button then both images comes closer to each other. How can do it? can someone please help me to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $('#pic1').animate({left:+=50});
    $('#pic2').animate({left:-=50});
});
```

Comment: I want this effect repeatedly. like after every one minute i want them to be close.

Comment: Can you provide me any link for that.Actually i am new to jquery so thats the problem

Comment: Hi i am getting some error near the "Left:+=50" of expected expression can you let me know to solve this

Comment: Put up a jsfiddle, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @R.S.Rana try putting `;` after 50

Comment: Just go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and select jOuery from the library box. Then put all the relevant pieces in the correct boxes. Don't forget to Save.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsingh333/rJjgB/ this is the url after pasting there code but i dont how to paste images and CSS

Comment: The CSS just goes in the CSS box. Just direct the images to absolute paths of random stuff for now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsingh333/rJjgB/6/ i have updated the question please see whats the prob why its not working for me

Comment: I changed a few things, so go to http://jsfiddle.net/rJjgB/10/ I hypothesise that the fact that you're using float is breaking it. Also, it looks like you ought to be using IDs for this.

Answer (score 0):

On button click, get both elements by jquery or java and change their postions. 
Write down your HTML so that I can help you with the code.